# What are attacks to execute code or modify webpages?

Tags: web, network-security

A friend of mine suffered an attack where all his index files (php or html) had an iframe injected. It got me thinking

I heard of sql injections and exploits on a site to do something it didnt intend you to do. But how might someone execute code or write/modify pages w/o ssh/ftp access? What are some web attacks on that?

PS: After updating wordpress he believes the security hole an ftp attack. But my question is on web attacks.

Comment: If you have a cms with file upload capabilities, it is possible that if this functionality has a bug in the code, an attacker can modify files on the server. Or just upload their own shell and modify what they want from there.

Comment: @twsaef: You should make that an answer. Also a server attack is uploading a png to a site then browsing to it via /path/to/my-avatar.png/pretend-its.php to execute php code (this attack works on nginx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cms with file upload capabilities, it is possible that if this functionality has a bug in the code, an attacker can modify files on the server. Or just upload their own shell and modify what they want from there